# Why wont the code below execute when a cell is double clicked on?

Tags: vba, double-click

The code below ran earlier but will not execute when a cell is double clicked.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_DoubleClick(ByVal Target As range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Font.Bold = False Then

            Target.Font.Bold = True
            Target.Font.Color = vbRed
    Else
            Target.Font.Bold = False
            Target.Font.Color = 1

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: use `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` instead.

Comment: The updated code reads:                                                                    Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Excel.range, Cancel As Boolean), but it still is not triggering.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: The event handler is tied to the worksheet it's implemented for. Make sure you're implementing the handler in the correct sheet's code-behind. BTW it's outright impossible that "the code below ran earlier". The method's signature doesn't match any of the `WorksheetEvents` interface, so it could never have been invoked. Put the cursor on the `If` statement and press F9 to make a breakpoint. Then double-click a cell. That's how you'll know if it's invoked or not. FWIW it works perfectly fine here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer to why it's not working (@Mat's Mug and @Scott Craner beat me to that *again*), but a shortened version of the code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    With Target.Font
        .Bold = Not .Bold
        .Color = Choose(Abs(CLng(.Bold)) + 1, 1, vbRed)
    End With

End Sub
```

Ok, not as easy to follow as the original but here's what it's doing:

`Target.Font.Bold` is either TRUE or FALSE, so `Not .Bold` will return the opposite.
Bold = TRUE so Not Bold = FALSE

`Abs(CLng(.Bold)) + 1`
Again, .Bold is either TRUE or FALSE.  Numerically TRUE = -1, FALSE = 0.

`CLNG(.Bold)` will return -1 or 0.
`ABS(CLNG(.Bold))` will return 1 or 0.
`Abs(CLng(.Bold)) + 1` will return 1 or 2 - which is used in the `CHOOSE` command to return `vbRed` or `1`.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have updated the code & all is well.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

**DO NOT** type any of these signatures manually!

Use the code pane dropdowns instead:

[image: code pane dropdowns]

Select `Worksheet` from the left dropdown, and pick an event to handle in the right dropdown; the VBE will generate a method stub with the proper signature for you.

Typing them out manually off the top of your head can (and does!) result with handlers that end up never being called, or worse, that *are* called, but are given parameter values in the wrong arguments, e.g. if `UserForm_QueryClose` is typed up manually with inverted parameters (the handler has 2 `Integer` parameters, so you need to remember the exact order.. otherwise you assign `Cancel` and the form understands that you assigned `CloseMode`)

If you're not seeing `Worksheet` in the left dropdown, then you're not in a worksheet's code-behind module. Worksheet events can only be handled in a worksheet module.

In a `Workbook` module (i.e. `ThisWorkbook`) you can handle the `SheetBeforeDoubleClick` event to handle a double-click on *any* worksheet in the workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

End Sub
```

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Excel.range, Cancel As Boolean)
     If Target.Font.ColorIndex <> 1 Then
         
         Target.Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 1
         Target.Font.Bold = False
     Else
         
         Target.Cells.Font.Color = vbRed
         Target.Font.Bold = True
     End If
     Cancel = True
End Sub

Comment: I have this Sub placed on the individual worksheet "Sheet 1".  It doe snot activate as expected.  What am I missing?  Thank you for the great feedback.

Comment: That exact code works here. The handler handles double-click events. Did you try setting a breakpoint (F9) inside the handler?

Comment: @t.mo your events may have been turned offed and not turned back on.

Comment: @ScottCraner gah, must be it! `Application.EnableEvents = True`

Comment: That is it.. The event were turned off.  I previously had the line in to turn them on.  Thank you for your timely response.  I ca't give you enough credit for your help.  thank you as always.