# Excel VBA WorkBook_sheetchange wont run

Tags: excel, vba

I cant make my code run in Excel VBA (office 365).

I would like to make this code to run after any cell is changed by user or code:

`

```
Sub Workbook_SC()

Dim var1 As Double

Application.EnableEvents = False

Worksheets("GSCells").Cells(5, 4).Value = 22

Worksheets("GSCells").Cells(5, 5).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Worksheets("GSCells").Cells(5, 4)

var1 = Worksheets("GSCells").Cells(5, 4).Value

Worksheets("GSCells").Cells(10, 5).Value = var1

If var1 < 23 Then
    Worksheets("Best").Cells(24, 11).Value = 23
End If

If var1 > 45 Then
    Worksheets("Best").Cells(24, 11).Value = 45
End If

If var1 >= 23 And var1 <= 45 Then
    Worksheets("Best").Cells(24, 11).Value = var1
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

`
I made this code based on info of this forum.
I have this code in 'ThisWorkbook' in Excel VBA.
Initially, The Sub was named Workbook_SheetChange() but it returned an error ("Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having same name").

This error disapeared after I changed its name to SC().
Dispite that, every time I change any value on any sheet, it just doesn't run.

However, if I go into VBA and press F5, it works fine.

Can someone help?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44311867/1188513).

Comment: Just Curious... Why are you using `Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` and not `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`? Also when working with the Sheet Change Event, you need to be slightly more careful. You may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure/13861640#13861640)

Comment: Or in short, forget the code for a moment. Can you tell me in "words" what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to trigger on the SheetChange() event it's important to have the required parameters in the Subroutine's definition:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
```

Any other name, or any other list of parameters will result in an error or no event triggering, both of which you've already experienced.

Comment: Many thanks for your help!!! Could you explain what means Sh (=Sheet) and Target (=Range?)?

Comment: Inside this subroutine you can use those variables. `sh` will hold the Worksheet upon which the change was made and `Target` will hold the range upon which the change was made. You could do the following code inside, for instance: `If Sh.Name = "Sheet1" Then Target.Value = "No Changes Allowed"`. So if the change was detected on tab `Sheet1` then the cell(s) will be set to the value "No Changes Allowed" (which would be really annoying).