# How do I make my macro run when 'save' is selected?

Tags: excel, vba

I am setting up a document to remove rows if a specific cell contains a value.  I want this code to run when the 'save' button is selected.  What do I need to add to my vba script to make this happen?

I have searched several sites and tried several suggested solutions but am not finding one that is working.

```
HideRows_BeforeSave()

Dim beginRow As Long
Dim endRow As Long
Dim chkCol As Long
Dim rowCnt As Long
Dim rngResult As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

beginRow = 3
endRow = 38
chkCol = 14

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Travel Expense Codes")

For rowCnt = beginRow To endRow
    If Cells(rowCnt, chkCol).Value = "X" Then
        Cells(rowCnt, chkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True

    Else
        Cells(rowCnt, chkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False

    End If
Next rowCnt
```

When this code is inserted into the 'ThisWorkbook' object I am getting no response when I run the macro.  When inserted into a 'Module', I can make the macro run but am not able to make it run with the 'save' selection.

Comment: You need to have in `ThisWorkbook`, but you cannot change the name of the `Workbook_BeforeSave` event.

Comment: Also, when deleting rows, you have to step backwards from end to the first.

Comment: braX - I'm not sure I understand what you mean?                              
 Darrell H, I have this in 'ThisWorkbook' but 'HideRows_BeforeSave()' is in error?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44311867/1188513 - in this case you want to be in `ThisWorkbook`, and pick "Workbook" from the left dropdown, and "BeforeSave" from the right dropdown. Never type event handler signatures by hand! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this? as @braX suggested, you need to start from the last row and make your way up to the first row. This code lies in 'ThisWorkbook' see the red circles.

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

  Dim beginRow As Long, endRow As Long, chkCol As Long, rowCnt As Long
  Dim rngResult As Range
  Dim ws As Worksheet

  beginRow = 3
  endRow = 38
  chkCol = 14

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Travel Expense Codes")

  For rowCnt = endRow To beginRow Step -1
    If Cells(rowCnt, chkCol).Value = "X" Then
      ws.Cells(rowCnt, chkCol).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
  Next rowCnt

End Sub
```

Comment: It worked!  :)  (I changed it to 'hide' the rows rather than delete them.) Thank you so much for your help!  Can I ask another question?  This function is based on an entry on another worksheet in my workbook, is it possible to make the row 'unhide' if a value is then entered on the corresponding worksheet after save?